# Local php web server on Windows 8

Tags: apache-2.2, windows, php

I'm trying to install Apache2 with PHP on Windows 8 RC but I can't make it work with EasyPHP or Wamp. In both cases the localhost is not responding. I already tried to modify the host file with no success. My problem is similar to this one but nobody answered : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11236418/local-server-for-windows-8-release-preview

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

EasyPHP and WAMP package aren't ready yet for Windows 8. However using XAMPP solved my problem !

Comment: you can select your own answer as the correct one